# A confusing use of 这种将

Tags: phrase-meaning

In this cold weather my brain won't function! Help!

I can find several examples of 这种将

This text is about 沙画。

In the examples 1 and 2 below, I think I can understand what 将 is doing, it is the same as 把，but in my sentence, I can't see what 将 refers to. I think I could rewrite 1a. to 1b. and 2a. to 2b. Are the b-versions correct?

1a. 他就是这种将生命系于理论的人。
1b. 他就是这种系生命于理论的人。
2a. 这种将图纸发出进行投标的工作, 是由采购部门进行的。
     
2b. 这种发出图纸进行投标的工作, 是由采购部门进行的。

What is 将 doing in the sentence below?? Is it a correct sentence? How can I rewrite it without 将？？

这种将静态的美术作品以动态方式呈现出来的艺术形式，增添了作品的生命力。

EDIT: Thanks a lot for the answers. It looks like I have this:

这种艺术方式增添了作品的生命力。

then the adjectival phrase:

[以动态方式来呈现静态美术作品的]

together gives Dan's sentence:

这种[以动态方式来呈现静态美术作品的]艺术形式，增添了作品的生命力。

and the original used 将.

The phrase in {} could be moved to further down if we don't use 将：

这种将{静态的美术作品}[以动态方式呈现出来{}的]艺术形式，增添了作品的生命力。

That was hard for me to follow!

Answer (score 3):

> 这种将静态的美术作品以动态方式呈现出来的艺术形式，增添了作品的生命力。

将 here means 把. One possible rewiting without 将:

> 这种以动态方式来呈现静态美术作品的艺术形式，增添了作品的生命力。

Your two 'b's are okay.

Answer (score 2):

> What is 将 doing in the sentence below?? Is it a correct sentence?

Yes, this sentence is grammatical. 将 as a disposal marker, disposes the object,

In "他就是这种将生命系于理论的人 the verb "系" (tie) dispose the object "生命" -- "take life and tie it to ..."

[他][就是][这种][将][生命][系于][理论][的人]

[he][is just][this type of][take][life][tie it to][theory][person who]

[他就是这种(**将**生命)系于理论的人] = [He is just the type of person who (**takes** life) and ties it to theory]

> How can I rewrite it without 将？？

You can remove the disposal marker 将 and write "他就是这种系生命于理论的人"

Let the subject "他" (he) to use the verb "系' (ties) to act on the direct object "生命", and the indirect object 理论 (theory) = "he ties life to theory" --> "He is the type of person who ties life to theory

> 这种将静态的美术作品以动态方式呈现出来的艺术形式
>
> [这种][以][动态方式][显现][静态美术][的][艺术形式]
>
> [this type of][using][dynamic form][to display][static art][of][art style]
>
> [这种以动态方式，显现静态美术的艺术形式] = [ This type of art style that uses dynamic form to display static art]
>
> [这种以动态方式，显现静态美术的艺术形式，增添了作品的生命力] = [ This type of art style that uses dynamic form to display static art, adds vitality to the work]